# What is the actual meaning of --query parameter in aws ec2 create-key-pair?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I searched online as well as in the documentation where it says that it is "A JMESPath query to use in filtering the response data." (from official documentation), what does the JMESPath query mean here what/where does the key-pair needs to search from to get the output.

It is a optional parameter but, when do we need it in, is it used in conmanly in production systems, which in turn may or may not make the use of the key-pair command easy for the administrator.

Below is the example I found on a course i am studying.

**# aws ec2 create-key-pair --key-name  --query 'KeyMaterial' --output
text > <keypair-Name.pem>**

I tried doing a chatgpt which gave a below solution, but didn't understand it completely. As it says it "looks for the value of the KeyMaterial field in the JSON output". Why does it have to look for this key-material/how is this useful for the command/system admin?

"--query 'KeyMaterial' is using the --query parameter to specify a JMESPath expression. In this case, it's looking for the value of the KeyMaterial field in the JSON output returned by the create-key-pair command. This field typically contains the actual private key material."

Comment: `--query` is used to filter the output produced by the command